# Trying to copy a row from one sheet to another based on the value in the first column of each row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to move yesterday's data off of one sheet onto another sheet(from one tab at the bottom to another tab at the bottom), then delete it off of the first sheet(while preserving the equations).

Here's an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LmCVKknqLre1SB8O0Deu2Tx7bM2yI3bdjF2wbVJ9JMY/edit?usp=sharing).

I have a google script running every night just after midnight, and I've tried to iterate through every single row, check if the first column has yesterday's date, then copy the row to the other sheet and delete the original row.

```
function moveDataNewSheet() {
  var DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID = "16cy4ClKYEN_w5_c6KiR2zSjRsUD9ijxQD9DGffNRXtI";
  var Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // create sheet with yesterdays date
  // if col1 has yesterdays date, 
  // then copy it to yesterdays sheet
  // delete row

  //get dateString
  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
  var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, 'EDT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  // create new sheet with yesterdays date
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(dateString);
  if (yourNewSheet != null) {
      activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
  }
  yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
  yourNewSheet.setName(dateString);

  //set active sheet to Sheet1
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(Sheet1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1);

  // if col1 has yesterdays date copy it to dateString's sheet
  // delete row
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var source_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(dateString);

  for (var i = 0; i < Sheet1.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if (Sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue() == Sheet1.getRange(i,1).substring(0,10)) {
      var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
      target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
      source_sheet.getRange(i,1).clear();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome. What is the problem with the script? FWIW, I think the source and destination sheets are both looking at the **same** spreadsheet - the active spreadsheet. But it's impossible to be sure because your source file doesn't contain any data. In addition, you imply that some cells on the source are formulas, but you don't say which, or explain why you want them retained when they are copied. Please provide a sample of the source spreadsheet containing data (the image is not enough), and please provide an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if that wasn't clear. I want to move data from one subsheet(the tabs on the bottom) to another subsheet, but keep everything in the same overall google spreadsheet. I'll edit the original post to make it more clear and add an example spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is trying to backup previous day data to a specific sheet and then delete that data from the source. The code is overly complicated lacks clarity and does not delete the rows from the source.

The processing sequence follows the OP's method:

1. Identify the source spreadsheet and sourcesheet.
2. Create a variable for to identify "yesterday's date".
3. Establish whether a sheet by that name exists in the source spreadsheet; if not, then create and rename a sheet.
4. Assign the new sheet as the targetsheet
5. get the number of rows of data. Normally `getLastRow` could be used, but this identified empty 'phantom' rows.
6. get **all** the data from the Sourcesheet prior to the loop
7. loop through the source data
8. build a header row and then evaluate each timestamp against the variable for "yesterday's date"
9. where the row date is a match, push values for each column onto a "rowarray", push the "row" array onto a "targetarray", clear the "rowarray" for the next row; increment a row counter.
10. when finished with the loop, update the target sheet with the "targetarray".
11. delete the rows from the sourcesheet.

---

```
function so_55537340_03() {

  // NOTE: code assumes that data is always in contiguous rows in date order

  // setup external sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<insert spreadsheet ID>");
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: ss = "+ss.getName());//DEBUG
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: source sheet: "+sourceSheet.getName());//DEBUG

  //get dateString
  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: yesterday: "+yesterday);//DEBUG
  var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, 'EDT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: datestring: "+dateString);//DEBUG

  // create new sheet with yesterdays date
  // get the sheet, returns null if not exist
  var yourNewSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dateString);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: yournewsheet: "+yourNewSheet);//DEBUG

  // test if sheet exists
  if (yourNewSheet != null) {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the spreadsheet is NOT null");//DEBUG
    // the sheet exists, so what??
    //ss.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
  } else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the spreadsheet is null");//DEBUG
    // the sheet doesn't exist, so create and rename the sheet
    yourNewSheet = ss.insertSheet();
    yourNewSheet.setName(dateString);
  }

  // assign a variable to the target sheet
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dateString);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: target sheet: "+targetSheet.getName());// DEBUG

  // get the number of rows of data in column A for a loop (getLastrow was unreliable)
  var Avals = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: source last row: "+Alast);//DEBUG

  // define the source range and get the data
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: sourcerange = "+sourceRange.getA1Notation()+", and number of rows of data: "+Alast);//DEBUG

  // establish arrays for pasting row results and total results to target sheet
  var targetData = [];
  var rowData = [];

  // create variable to count rows to delete
  var rowcounter = 0;

  // loop through the source data
  for (var i = 0; i < Alast; i++) {

    // clear rowData before each new row
    rowData = [];

    // test for row 1/headers
    if (i == 0) {

      // build the header row in the target
      rowData.push(sourceData[i][0]);
      rowData.push(sourceData[i][1]);
      rowData.push(sourceData[i][2]);
      rowData.push(sourceData[i][3]);
      rowData.push(sourceData[i][4]);
      rowData.push(sourceData[i][5]);
      rowData.push(sourceData[i][6]);
      rowData.push(sourceData[i][7]);

      // push row data on targetData
      targetData.push(rowData);
    }

    // process for rows other than header
    if (i > 0) {

      //Logger.log("DEBUG: rowdate: "+sourceData[i][0]);//DEBUG
      // get the substring
      var sourcecelldate = sourceData[i][0].substring(0, 10);
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: data substring: "+sourcecelldate);//DEBUG

      // if the data substring equals the datestring for yesterday
      if (sourcecelldate == dateString) {
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: dates align, do something");//DEBUG
        // build the data for the row
        rowData.push(sourceData[i][0]);
        rowData.push(sourceData[i][1]);
        rowData.push(sourceData[i][2]);
        rowData.push(sourceData[i][3]);
        rowData.push(sourceData[i][4]);
        rowData.push(sourceData[i][5]);
        rowData.push(sourceData[i][6]);
        rowData.push(sourceData[i][7]);

        // push row data on targetData
        targetData.push(rowData);
        rowcounter++
        Logger.log("Row counter: " + rowcounter);

      } else {
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: dates DO NOT align, do nothing");//DEBUG
      }
    }

  } // end of loop 

  // get number of rows of targetdata
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: length of targetdata"+targetData.length);//DEBUG
  // define the data range for the target sheet  
  var targetrows = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetData.length, 8);
  // paste the data onto the targetsheet
  targetrows.setValues(targetData);

  // delete the old rows from the source sheet
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: number of rows to delete = "+rowcounter);
  sourceSheet.deleteRows(2, rowcounter);

}
```

---

I have left "Logger" statements in the following code to troubleshoot values at various stages in the process.